# What arguments does Svante Arrhenius make in 1896 to prove the correlation between "carbonic acid" and ground temperature increase?

Tags: climate-change

I tried reading Arrhenius' paper (https://www.rsc.org/images/Arrhenius1896_tcm18-173546.pdf), but having no background in natural sciences, it was too inaccessible to me. What is the high-level outline of the consecutive steps of his line of argumentation?